# Having Mathematica automatically plug in the values for a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have a set of pairs, such as `{{8 a, 2 + 2 a}, {8 b, 1 + 3 a}}`.  This set encodes the fact that I want to put `8a == 2+2a` and `8b == 1+3b`.  I can manually type

```
Solve[8a==2+2a&&8b==1+3a]
```

to figure out that `a -> 1/3` and `b -> 1/4` are the solutions of this system, and then type

```
a = 1/3; b = 1/4;
```

to set the variables to their actual values.  However, I'd like to have Mathematica set `a=1/3` and `b=1/4` for me, to use in later computations. In the actual example I'm working with, the number of variables is much larger, but the equations are still all linear and have a unique solution.  Thus, it is tiresome to go through each variable one-by-one and plug in its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below accomplishes what you asked. However, note that once a and b have been assigned values they can no longer be used as unknowns for further work. An alternative is to assign values to another symbol set, or to simply preserve a list of solutions for use when all equations have been solved.

```
expr = {{8 a, 2 + 2 a}, {8 b, 1 + 3 a}};

makeEquations[lst_] := 
 lst /. {{t1_, t2_}, {t3_, t4_}} -> t1 == t2 && t3 == t4

makeEquations[expr]

(* 8 a\[Equal]2+2 a&&8 b\[Equal]1+3 a *)

sol = Solve[makeEquations[expr], {a, b}][[1]]

(*  {a -> 1/3, b -> 1/4} *)

{a, b} = {a, b} /. sol
```

Comment: @PaceNielsen. Yeah, I mean, I would leave `a` and `b` undefined and just use the replacement rules generated from `Solve`. This is idiomatic in *Mathematica*.

Comment: To convert the lists into equations, `Apply` `Equal` to level 1 of the lists. 

`eqns = Equal @@@ lists`

Comment: This helped me cobble together code that does what I need.  Special thanks to march and Bob Hanlon!

Answer (score 2):

Replace rules by variable setters:

```
Solve[8 a == 2 + 2 a && 8 b == 1 + 3 a] /. Rule -> Set
```

After this, the variables are set to $a=\frac13$ and $b=\frac14$.

This trick assumes that there's only one set of solutions.